# How can I copy data from amazon S3 to redshift automatically?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

First I would like to let you know how am I coping right now.

> I am coping data manually from S3 to redshift i.e. using copy command in SQL Workbench. And sometimes I execute this command via JDBC option.

I think this is not the right option to copy data. There may be a good solution to copy. I want to copy data automatically when new data comes in S3. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I would work with lambda.

1. you can trigger a lamdba when new object are inserted to S3 ([see doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html))
2. depending how much data you'll have to copy from S3, it might be preferable to aggregate the work so the work will be faster

AWS has released [code from labs](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-redshift-loader) that loads the data from S3 buckets to redshift.

[This blog from amazon](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx24VJ6XF1JVJAA/A-Zero-Administration-Amazon-Redshift-Database-Loader) takes a lot of the doc from the github project to see how to put it in practice.

Comment: This is more efficient way than mine reverting back my answer. :)

Comment: could you please share code in python if available, though I found it in javascript in your github but wanted to implement in python. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Lambda approach seems pretty good and well trodden. As an alternative also consider AWS Glue. It isn't terribly straightforward to configure, but it seems built to handle this sort of workflow.